# How do I get input from user for two diffrent instances?

Tags: java, oop, input

I'm creating a program that displays an employee's name and salary. the name and salary is entered by the user and I want to make two employees i.e. two instances. How to get two seperate inputs from the user?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class Employee {

```
String first_name;
String last_name;
double pay = 0;

public Employee(double p, String f, String l) {
    first_name = f;
    last_name = l;
    pay = p;
}

public void name_printer(){
    //To collect Area
   System.out.println("Your name is "+ first_name+" "+last_name+".");   
}

public void pay_printer(){
    //To collect Area
    pay=pay*12;
    System.out.println("Your yearly pay is "+ pay+".");   
}

public void pay_update(){
    //To collect Area
    pay=pay*12;
    pay=pay+(pay*0.1);        
   System.out.println("Your raised yearly pay is "+ pay+".");   
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter first name ");
    String in1_f = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter last name ");
    String in1_l = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter your monthly pay ");
    double user1_p = input.nextDouble();
    double in1_p=0;
    if (user1_p>0){
        in1_p=user1_p;
    } 
    Employee employee1 = new Employee(in1_p, in1_f, in1_l);
    employee1.name_printer();
    employee1.pay_printer();
    employee1.pay_update();

}
```

Comment: Your code is getting input from the user with `input.nextLine()`.  What exactly is stopping you from using that three more times to get the information about the next employee?...

Comment: I thought you were wondering how to get it right in terms of design. In this case your best is to reuse the code, I had posted an answer which shows how to do it

Answer (score 0):

To get your design slightly more convenient you should follow one of the main programmers' habits - reuse the code:

```
// Note that I marked Scanner as final, 
// since it shouldn't be modified inside the method
public Employee createEmployee(final Scanner input) {
    System.out.print("Enter first name ");
    String in1_f = input.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Enter last name ");
    String in1_l = input.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Enter your monthly pay ");
    double user1_p = input.nextDouble();
    double in1_p=0;

    if (user1_p>0){
        in1_p=user1_p;
    } 

    System.out.println("All data is provided, creating instance...");
    return new Employee(in1_p, in1_f, in1_l);
}
```

And then in main func:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
Employee e1 = createEmployee(input);
Employee e2 = createEmployee(input); // and so on...
```

To get all data about an instance just override `toString()` method in your employee class (it is preferred over creating your own print methods):

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder s1 = new StringBuilder();
    s1.append("Some information " + someInformation + "\n");
    // construct the string which will represent your object
    return s1.toString();
}
```

And then:

```
System.out.println(e1.toString());
```